# How to edit the group-by headers of Vuetify <v-data-table>?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to edit the `group-by` headers of Vuetify `<v-data-table>` ?

I need to **hide the cross** and **set a custom title**.

[image]

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    group-by="category"
></v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to override default **group.header** slot.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    group-by="category"
>
  <template v-slot:group.header="{items, isOpen, toggle}">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">
      <v-icon @click="toggle">
        {{ isOpen ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus' }}
      </v-icon>
      <span>Your custom header w/o cross</span>
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Check [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables) in Slots category to get full list of available props in this slot.